# Why wont the while loop stop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I think im missing something here to make the while loop end because everytime I try to calculate the average for everything it asks me if I have another client to enter. Also, what am I missing to get the average for everyone? The value I get is never right.

```
csum=0
ccount=0
clients=int(input("How Many Clients?"))
while clients==clients:
    sum=0
    counter=0
    determiner=str(input("Do you have another client to enter?"))
    if determiner==str('Yes' or "Y" or "YES"):
        clientname=str(input("What is the client's name?"))
        for i in range(4):
            stock=int(input("Enter Stock Amount:"))
            sum=sum+stock
            counter=counter+1
            avg=sum/counter
            csum=csum+avg
        print("The Average for",clientname,"is:",avg)
    if determiner==str('No' or 'no' or 'NO'):
        cavg=csum/clients
        print("The average for all the clients is:",f'{cavg:.2f}')
```

And **output** is:

```
How Many Clients? 3
Do you have another client to enter?Yes
What is the client's name?Owen
Enter Stock Amount:5000
Enter Stock Amount:-6000
Enter Stock Amount:7000
Enter Stock Amount:3000
The Average for Owen is: 2250.0
Do you have another client to enter?Yes
What is the client's name?John
Enter Stock Amount:1000
Enter Stock Amount:2000
Enter Stock Amount:3000
Enter Stock Amount:4000
The Average for John is: 2500.0
Do you have another client to enter?Yes
What is the client's name?Matt
Enter Stock Amount:7000
Enter Stock Amount:8000
Enter Stock Amount:6000
Enter Stock Amount:5600
The Average for Matt is: 6650.0
Do you have another client to enter? No
The average for all the clients is: 14633.33
Do you have another client to enter?
```

Comment: `while clients==clients` == `while true` (depending on the language)

Comment: Seems like you just need to toss a `break` after your last print.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions for your code:

- Change `while clients==clients` to `while True`
- Remove `str` conversions. Inputs are `str` by default.
- Change `if` conditions to:

```
    if determiner.lower() in {"yes", "y"}: ...
    if determiner.lower() in {"no", "n"}: ...
```

- You can use less amount of variables to achieve the same result
- The answer to your problem according to this code is the missing `break`:

```
    if determiner.lower() in {"no", "n"}:
        cavg = csum/clients
        print(f"The average for all the clients is: {cavg:.2f}")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is with missing `break` statement here

```py
if determiner==str('No' or 'no' or 'NO'):
    cavg=csum/clients
    print("The average for all the clients is:",f'{cavg:.2f}')
    break
```

Also, if you have had already asked for number of clients `int(input("How Many Clients?"))` why not just use this to create a for loop and you would not even need to ask if there is another client:

```py
clients=int(input("How Many Clients?"))
csum = 0
number_of_stocks = 4
for i in range(clients):
    client_sum=0
    clientname=str(input(f"What is the client #{i+1}'s name?"))
    for i in range(number_of_stocks):
        stock=int(input("Enter Stock Amount:"))
        client_sum+=stock
    avg=client_sum/number_of_stocks 
    csum=csum+avg
    print("The Average for",clientname,"is:",avg)

cavg = csum/clients
print("The average for all the clients is:",f'{cavg:.2f}')
```

Furthermore I have had changed `sum` to `client_sum` as it is a keyword in Python.